# Safari reloading web page 3 times during redirect

Tags: redirect, go, safari

For the life of me I thought I was going mad because as far as I could see everything was/is ok with the code in that regards. Out of exasperation I decided to try my application in another browser and found that in Chrome and FF the app works fine, but in Safari for some reason it refreshes the page 3 times. I've tried resetting Safari and turning off extensions in case that was the issue but the same thing happens.

I'm not sure if this is just a quirk with my setup, or potentially my code so I've pasted it here below to have some other eyes look at it. If more code/context is required, please let me know. In essence it takes the user to the index page, the movie page and repeats this process 3 times.

```
func movieHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    command := r.URL.Query().Get("command")
    film := r.URL.Query().Get("movie")

    if pageData.Player.Playing == false {
        if film == "" {
            log.Println("No film was selected")
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
        err := pageData.Player.StartFilm(film)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Following error occurred: %v\n", err)
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
        pageData.CurrentFilm = film
    } else if pageData.Player.Playing && (film == "" || pageData.Player.FilmName == film) {
        if command == "kill" {
            err := pageData.Player.EndFilm()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Following error occurred: %v\n", err)
            }
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
            return
        } else if command != "" {
            err := pageData.Player.SendCommandToFilm(command)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Following error occurred: %v\n", err)
            }
        }
    } else {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
        return
    }
    renderTemplate(w, "movie.html")
}
```

Note: I'm still an inexperienced coder (especially with go), so additional input on improving this code in any other way is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if the browser request favicon.ico multiple times?

Comment: @SimoEndre, how would I check to see if it's looking for that? (I'm guessing it's in the developer tools there in Safari?) but I see no mention of favicon anywhere.. I don't have one set up in any case.

Comment: This is a browser specific functionality, even if you are not setting up, it will look for it. Yes, please check the network panel from developer tools.

Comment: Had a look at the network section, the only things listed are various css and javascript files. No mention of favicon.